# syntax error, unexpected token "<<", expecting "function" or "const"

Tags: php, php-8

I read this [article](https://php.watch/articles/php-attributes#syntax) after upgrading my local dev environment to php8.

And implement it in my class, like:

```
<<Attribute('foo')>>
public function index()
{
    $posts = (new Post)->get()->withMany('image');

    return $this->app()->view('index', compact('posts'));
}
```

and it return error.

> syntax error, unexpected token "<<", expecting "function" or "const"

What is really a proper of doing that in php8. Am i missing something?

Comment: Also note that article was written back in May before PHP 8 was finalized. [Here](https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-8) is a more up to date article on the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct attribute syntax in PHP 8 is:

```
#[Attribute('foo')]
```

https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php

Comment: To clarify why people might find examples with the wrong syntax: there was a lot of debate about what to use, and it was actually changed several times during the pre-release period of PHP 8. So, for some pre-8.0.0 builds, `<<Attribute>>` was in fact the correct syntax.

Comment: Still not understood how to use this new concept :(

Answer (score -1):

```
public function create(Request $request)//create object of the request
{ 
    $student = new Student;//create object of the model
    $student->name = $request->name;
    $student->city = $request->city;
    $student->marks = $request->marks;
    $student->save();
    return redirect('index');//if we write this out of the curly braces then this error show

    
}
```

Comment: Your solution is not related to the question asked.